# font-awesome fonts not loading in production, but loading fine using webpack-dev-server

Tags: fonts, sass, webpack

I'm trying to use font-awesome in a project. I'm using webpack-dev-server while developing and the fonts load fine, but when I build using webpack and open the result (locally or hosted on a server), the `woff`, `woff2`, and `ttf` files all fail to load.

I'm using the `file-loader` module to handle all of the font types like this:

```
{test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)/, loader: "file"},
```

And I'm including the font-awesome SASS file like this:

```
$fa-font-path: "./font-awesome-4.5.0/fonts";
@import "./font-awesome-4.5.0/scss/font-awesome.scss";
```

The result of my webpack build is a folder with my `index.html`, `bundle.js`, and all of the font files. The Chrome developer console shows the files failing to load, but they have the correct file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was my webpack config had `publicPath: "/"`, so the files were being requested at the root of my file system rather than my project's directory.

Changing it to `publicPath: ""` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try include it as a vendor dependency, not within sass: `npm i -D font-awesome`. It's probably that the font paths aren't matching correctly.

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './js/index.js',
    vendor: [
      'font-awesome\css\font-awesome.css',
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: 'bundles',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.css', 'scss']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['style', 'css'] },
      { test: /\.woff2?(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream" },
      { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file" },
      { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml" }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(
      'vendor', '[name].js'
    )
  ]
};
```

The css it's going to include it inline with the vendor.js file.

Comment: I don't see how it could be a path issue though. The output of my build includes all of the font files and when the server requests them, it's without a path. For example, my build has a `a3de2170e4e9df77161ea5d3f31b2668.ttf` file, and when I run the `index.html`, the console says `GET file:///a3de2170e4e9df77161ea5d3f31b2668.ttf net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. I know the file is there, and it's requesting the correct file path.

Comment: is `file:///a3de2170e4e9df77161ea5d3f31b2668.ttf ` the exact path of the fonts in the console?

Comment: Yes. I think I actually just found the issue. I had `publicPath: "/"` in my webpack config, but it should be `publicPath: ""`. This seems to have fixed the issue.